# How can check all array keys are include subkey

Tags: php

How can check that all keys are include sub key.

```
$array1 = array("key1"=>"sub1", "key2"=>"sub2"); // true

$array2 = array("key1", "key2"=>"sub2"); // false
$array3 = array("key1"=>"sub1", "key2"); // false
$array4 = array("key1", "key2"); // false

if(checkSubKey($array1)) 
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: No idea what you want to do

Comment: @Rizier123 For validation.
if subkey not exists, my method not work correctly. i want throw a exception

Comment: @u_mulder No, i need check subkey exists for all keys.

Comment: @u_mulder `"key1"=>"sub1" `.. I want to know sub defined or no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array1 = array("key1"=>"sub1", "key2"=>"sub2");


$hasKey = true;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if(!is_string($key))
    {
        $hasKey = false;
    }
}

var_dump($hasKey); //true

$array2 = array("key1", "key2"=>"sub2");

$hasKey = true;
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    if(!is_string($key))
    {
        $hasKey = false;
    }
}

var_dump($hasKey); //false
```

This method will work provided you do not assign your own numeric keys. All array positions have an index. If you don't assign one, it will be numerical by default. This method takes advantage of that by assuming that if the array element doesn't have a string-based key, then its key is missing. Although not technically true, it's true enough to satisfy your example.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a good Note: `If you don't assign one, it will be numerical by default`

Comment: @M. Esmaeili No problem. It's good to be aware of the limitations of any solution, in case your needs change in future.

Comment: Sorry, I can not vote because of lack of Reputation +1 ... Thanks again

Comment: @M. Esmaeili. No problem at all. I'm just glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use foreach for this.

```
 $flag=true; 
 foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
{ 
  if(!($key && $value))
   {  
    $flag= false; 
    break;  
   } 
 }

if($flag==false)
{ 
   //your stuff 
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work. All arrays have keys. If it doesn't have an explicit key, it has an implicit numeric-based key. Also, you're missing an & in your if statement expression.

Comment: This will work... even first i tried it then posted and i wonder when i got to know while testing that only & and also working correctly.

Comment: I can see how it works now. As soon as it encounters an implicit key, it will be assigned the first numeric index of 0, which is a falsy value. I think your solution is actually more elegant than mine, but a little less readable. A good solution all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try array_key_exists()
Return true if array has key or false if not.

```
 if(array_key_exists("key",$yourarray))
 {
      echo "exists";
  }

 {
      else "not exist";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to know subkey defined for all keys or not.

Comment: You can also use foreach for this.
     $flag=true;
     foreach($arr as $key)
    {
       if!($key)
        {
          $flag= false;
         break;
        }
   }

    if($flag==false){
       //your stuff
    }

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that a particular key exists in an array, you can make use of php's [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php) method:

```
if (array_key_exists("key1", $array1))
{
   echo "Key exists!";
}
```

You could make use of regular expressions as well, with a little difference though (*using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) method*):

```
foreach($array1 as $key=> $value){
     if(preg_match("/^key/", $key)){ //regular expression
         echo "this key exists";
     }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to determine whether a key holds an array itself (*i.e. a sub-array*), you could do the following:

```
foreach($array1 as $a){
   if(is_array($a)){
       //do some stuff on the inner array
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to know subkey defined for all keys or not.

Comment: Sorry, but by _subkey_ do you mean that a key is holding an array or what. Refering to something like `"key1"=>"sub1" `, _sub1_ is actually the **value** and NOT a subkey,  which itself can be an array as well, and which can further contain _key_ and _value_ pairs.

Comment: Yes you are right. my sub1 always is a value. and single

Comment: In fact, I need to the results of my example in question.